# Absit Invidia as a command

Tags: classical-latin

I've read on Stack Exchange that Absit Invidia means "May Malice Be Gone". Can one also use it then, for example,  when a pesky terrible person leave the room, or even say it to them as a command (i.e. to get out because of their malice)? Or is it *only* a wish?

Basically, I want something other than "bug off" and "F* you" to say against the nasty people I have to work and deal with. This would be relevant in two scenarios: 1. They are there and I want them to leave. 2. They have just left and I want to 'relieve' my soul of them.

Comment: If you want to see it as a command, how would you phrase it in English or some other language? I imagine "may malice be gone" and "go away, you malicious one" can have the same effect in some situations, but the nuance is different.

Comment: Thanks! I edited that explanation into your question. Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks Joonas, as always. Joonas and CMW, the usual suspects! :) Much obliged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pun on it but make it a command, try: *Absis, invidia*, "May you, malice, be gone." *Absis* is the second person singular, and though it still expresses a wish, it's no different than in English in that respect. (Think of it like a curse.)

If someone has just left, you can use the simple present: *Invidia abest*, "The malice is away."

Comment: Thanks alot. That answers my question and addresses both circumstances (when they're there, and when they've left). Fantastic.